# How to keep Wordcloud layout in R

Tags: r, layout, word-cloud, tag-cloud

I have a Wordcloud with 29 words and I want to have different pictures where I change the color of each category of words. My problem is that everytime I run the Wordcloud again the location of the words change while I want to keep it fixed. Any idea?

In the code below you have the list of words and frequency and then I specify three different types of colorlist. When you run it colors change but the layout also (i.e. words are positioned in different location).

```
name <- c("Trump","Central bank", "Brexit", "Inflation", "Employment", "China",
   "Trade", "Bond Market", "Equity market","Economic Growth", "Tax reform",
   "Monetary Policy","ECB","FED","Macron","oil prices", "Market volatility",
   "Cyber risk", "North Korea", "Financial crisis","Fiscal Policy",
   "Emerging Markets","Political uncertainty","Saudi Arabia","Exchange rates",
   "Housing Markets","Le Pen","Merkel","Healthcare")


colorlist=c("grey","red","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey",
            "grey","grey","red","red","red","grey","grey","grey","grey",
            "grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey")

# Frequency count of the words
freq=c(2044,1978,1938,1826,1722,1483,1434,1352,1343,1270,1209,1179,1114,925,
       816,762,744,654,572,545,476,466,432,406,370,326,282,243,236)
```

The code I have tried running is:

```
library(wordcloud)
set.seed(512)
wordcloud(name, freq, random.order=FALSE,fixed.asp=TRUE,
             colors=colorlist, ordered.colors=TRUE)
```

Some example outputs highlighting the problem:

[image]

Comment: I used wordcloud2 in the end which does note seem to have this issue. BTW even using set.seed() I could not force wordcloud() to use the same layout...

Comment: Were you running the code line by line within R or executing the whole script at once? If you run the whole script at once it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this problem on Linux R 3.4.2. Starting a fresh R session (`R --vanilla`) and calling the following repeatedly generates the exact same plot each time

```
set.seed(512)
wordcloud(name, freq, random.order=FALSE, fixed.asp=TRUE, colors=colorlist, ordered.colors=TRUE)
```

Here's a smaller example that also works and is useful for troubleshooting:

```
set.seed(42)
wordcloud::wordcloud(letters, freq = seq_along(letters))
```

## Details

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] wordcloud_2.5      RColorBrewer_1.1-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 Rcpp_0.12.13   slam_0.1-40
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!